# Why to modify Java code while adding "Up button" in activity?

Tags: android

My aim is to add **Up button** to the Activity. The reason to question is that it is accomplished successfully just by adding **android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"** in AndroidManifest.xml

Now, I am wondering why
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral#java suggest us to make changes in the java code.

---

Android Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.miwok">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NumbersActivity" android:label="Numbers" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>

</application>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

For devices running **Android 4.1(API level 16) and above**, you can specify the `android:parentActivityName` attribute in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

But if the app is targeting devices **below** Android 4.1, then you need to add the parent activity information in the `<meta-data>` tag and add the java code that uses the `NavUtils` class for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

By modifying the java code you can adjust the appearance in the gui.

In different Android versions there are various appearances. For example the style of the back arrow changed. Furthermore, depending on the android version the app icon is clickable. When you want to influence this behavior you can do it by writing java code.

For a close look I suggest : http://codetheory.in/difference-between-setdisplayhomeasupenabled-sethomebuttonenabled-and-setdisplayshowhomeenabled/

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I am wondering why
>   https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral#java
>   suggest us to make changes in java code.

Referring to your statement, I assume you are talking about this code snippet below.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The reason for adding this code to your android java file is to allow you to have more customisation towards the action bar, just in case you want to change the default back option, such as UI and functionality (for example: you can perform some action such as sending a request to the server before returning to the parent?)